# POST Complex type to WebAPI from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ChangePassword")]
public string ChangePassword(Models.User value)
{
    return "";
}
```

And structure of `User` class is

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }    
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }    
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And I am calling this from JQuery

```
var value = { 'Username': name.val(), 'OldPassword': oldPassword.val(), 'NewPassword': newpassword.val() };
var b = JSON.stringify(value);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://tryURL/api/service/ChangePassword",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(value),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    }
});
```

Now when I debug the web service, it gives me an object but within the object, all properties are null. I have also tried to put `[fromBody]` in parameter but it does not work.

Comment: Note it's unusual to use `ActionName` in Web API. The *"action"* should be considered the *HTTP Verb* (GET, POST, etc.) that you're performing on the *HTTP Resource*. See [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, it may work

```
var value = {};
value.Username=name.val();
//etc
```

in ajax

```
data: JSON.stringify(value),//no change
```

Then remove `var b = JSON.stringify(value);`

Answer (score 0):

```
data: 'value=' + JSON.stringify(value)
```